# How can I install emacs 27 in ubuntu LTS (18.04.1)?

Tags: 18.04, lts, emacs

Question says it all, emacs 27 doesn't seem to be available through apt-get on my ubuntu version nor PPAs. Does that mean I have to build it from source? Thank you.

Comment: https://snapcraft.io/emacs  shows 26.3 from the stable channel, 27.0.90 from beta, and 28.0.50 from edge channels.

Comment: @guiverc ah, is that what the snap installing thing uses? I will look into it, thank you

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I compiled it from source on Ubuntu 16.04 (there's also [instructions in the Emacs documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Installing-Emacs.html)):

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338317/what-is-makeinfo-and-how-do-i-get-it
sudo apt install --yes texinfo
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297581/build-emacs-ubuntu-libraries-not-found
sudo apt install --yes libxpm-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev libtiff-dev libgnutls28-dev

git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/emacs.git /tmp/emacs \
    && cd /tmp/emacs \
    && git checkout emacs-27 \
    && ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make \
    && mv ./src/emacs /usr/bin/emacs \
    && rm -rf /tmp/emacs
```

Also, if you want to use [Doom Emacs](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/), you'll also need:

```
# rg
# https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/releases
curl -LO https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/releases/download/11.0.2/ripgrep_11.0.2_amd64.deb \
    && sudo dpkg -i ripgrep_11.0.2_amd64.deb \
    && rm ripgrep_11.0.2_amd64.deb
# fd
# https://github.com/sharkdp/fd/releases
curl -LO https://github.com/sharkdp/fd/releases/download/v8.1.1/fd-musl_8.1.1_amd64.deb \
    && sudo dpkg -i fd-musl_8.1.1_amd64.deb \
    && rm fd-musl_8.1.1_amd64.deb

git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs ~/.emacs.d
~/.emacs.d/bin/doom install
```

Comment: I've to run `make install` to get the doom part working

Comment: @Āchahms "I've" doesn't work the way you are using it.

Comment: do you think it has to do with `su` mode or something, i was trying to run all this in `su` shell. sorry completely new to debian/linux

Comment: the error i was getting: `Warning: arch-dependent data dir '/usr/local/libexec/emacs/27.2.50/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/': No such file or directory`

Comment: And maybe add `sudo apt install libjansson-dev` to get native JSON support compiled in

Answer (score 6):

```
snap install emacs --beta --classic
```

Comment: yeah this worked, i had to install emacs26 from the PPA for the snap to work though.... more info here https://github.com/alexmurray/emacs-snap/issues/11

Comment: ok so since I had emacs26 installed I had to clean emacs config, since I was using doom-emacs this meant delete ~/.emacs.d/.local then run `doom sync` to reinstall. Then it worked without emacs26